# 4clojure #57 - Simple Recursion

Tags: recursion, clojure

I am going through 4clojure problems and I cannot figure why [following code is working](https://www.4clojure.com/problem/57)

```
user=> ((fn foo [x] (when (> x 0) (conj (foo (dec x)) x))) 5)
(5 4 3 2 1)
```

I understand that `(foo (dec x))` has to be treated as a PersistentCollection for this to work but what is going on there is a mystery. Any insight why it is working, and why in this order will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's have a closer look at your code example. Basically, it's just a function call `(foo 5)` with the following `foo` function:

```clj
(defn foo [x]
  (when (> x 0)
    (conj (foo (dec x)) x)))
```

When you call `foo` with any non-positive value of `x` it returns `nil`. Otherwise it return a result of `conj`oining `x` to the result of calling `(foo (dec x))`.

So, calling `(foo 2)` is a rough equivalent of the following code:

```clj
(conj (conj nil 1) 2)
```

The thing that may confuse you is `conj` behavior with `nil` value passed as its first argument.

`conj` threats `nil` as an empty list `()`, so `(conj nil 1)` produces the same result as `(conj () 1)`. This behavior is documented in `conj` docs:

```
=> (doc conj)
(doc conj)
-------------------------
clojure.core/conj
([coll x] [coll x & xs])
  conj[oin]. Returns a new collection with the xs
    'added'. (conj nil item) returns (item).  The 'addition' may
    happen at different 'places' depending on the concrete type.
```

The other thing that may confuse you is the order of elements in the resulting list. `conj` is designed to add new element to the `PersistentCollection` in the most efficient way. In case of lists `conj`  adds new element to the beginning of the original list:

```
=> (conj '(1) 2)
(2 1)
```

Comment: What really helped me to understand conj was when you explained about the order. From my undrstanding conj would always _append_ but now I understand why not. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let's break this down:

```
(foo 5) ;;=>
(conj (foo 4) 5) ;;=>
(conj (conj (foo 3) 4) 5) ;;=>
...
(conj (conj (conj (conj (conj nil 1) 2) 3) 4) 5)
;; (conj nil 1) == '(1), so:
;;=>
(conj (conj (conj (conj '(1) 2) 3) 4) 5)
;; conj-ing adds to the head of the list
;;=>
(conj (conj (conj '(2 1) 3) 4) 5)
;;=> 
(conj (conj '(3 2 1) 4) 5)
...
;;=> '(5 4 3 2 1)
```